# How can I get a footer with 2 contents 100% lenght of every monitor

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create an footer to my project, but now i have the problem how to get the footer to the full size of the monitor. There I have my footer code and then my css.

```css
.container {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.container h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', 'sans-serif';
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(106,106,106,1.00);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.container a:hover {
    color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Finanzdienstleistung</h1>
            <a href="#">Versicherungen</a><br>
            <a href="#">Schadensabwickelung</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Vermietung</h1>
            <a href="#">Freie Wohnungen</a><br>
            <a href="#">Alle Wohnungen</a>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn them to `display: table-cell` instead of floats, to keep them in one row and filling the full width:

```css
footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    display: table-cell;
}

.container h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', 'sans-serif';
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(106,106,106,1.00);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.container a:hover {
    color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Finanzdienstleistung</h1>
            <a href="#">Versicherungen</a><br>
            <a href="#">Schadensabwickelung</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Vermietung</h1>
            <a href="#">Freie Wohnungen</a><br>
            <a href="#">Alle Wohnungen</a>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Is there any posibillity to let there a bigger padding left and right of the contents so that it looks like on the apple website as a example?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following. Just adding: `width: 50%` to container fixes it

```css
.container {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

.container h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', 'sans-serif';
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(106,106,106,1.00);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.container a:hover {
    color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Finanzdienstleistung</h1>
            <a href="#">Versicherungen</a><br>
            <a href="#">Schadensabwickelung</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Vermietung</h1>
            <a href="#">Freie Wohnungen</a><br>
            <a href="#">Alle Wohnungen</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
```